# Render public html for dynamic banners in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, banner

I would like to render specific **HTML snippets** for displaying banners, because each banner has a different nature (some images, some flash, etc). Every banner file is under app/public/banners/. I tried many ways, like:

```
render :file => "/banners/somebanner.html"
```

But it can't locate the file, because Rails looks under **app/views**. Any ideas ? Thanks!

> *Missing template banners/somebanner.html in view path app/views*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tired it but just found this post on Google

```
render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/banners/somebanner.html"
```

looks like there might be some caching side-effects, even in development mode

http://workingwithrails.com/forums/4-ask-a-rails-expert/topics/1178-render-file-rails-root-public-layouts-mylayout-cached

also you probably want :layout => false with that

Comment: As you predicted it fails to cache the content :(

Comment: what about in staging or production mode? ideally it is not caching in development mode so changes show up without restarting the server - the issue from that link was that it was caching during development mode?

Comment: `RAILS_ROOT` is deprecated use `Rails.root` now

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Fix:

Moved 'public/banners' to 'app/views/banners' and then made a synmlink in '/public' so my team can add new banners